# How do I declare a function parameter to accept functions that throw?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, kotlin, throws

I have defined a function in Kotlin:

```
fun convertExceptionToEmpty(requestFunc: () -> List<Widget>): Stream<Widget> {
    try {
        return requestFunc().stream()
    } catch (th: Throwable) {
        // Log the exception...
        return Stream.empty()
    }
}
```

I have defined a Java method with this signature:

```
List<Widget> getStaticWidgets() throws IOException;
```

I attempt to compose them like so:

```
Stream<Widget> widgets = convertExceptionToEmpty(() ->  getStaticWidgets())
```

When I compile I get this error:

> Error:(ln, col) java: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

How do I define my function parameters to accept a function that throws?

Comment: You could try annotating your convertExceptionToEmpty-function to throw an IOException, that could possibly bypass this error.

Comment: @piwo, I don't think this will help, exception is coming from ``getStaticWidgets()`` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Java has [checked exceptions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#checked-exceptions) but Kotlin does not. The requestFunc parameter type `() -> List<Widget>` will be mapped to the functional interface [Function0<List<Widget>>](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/jvm/functions/Functions.kt#L22) but the operator [invoke](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/jvm/functions/Functions.kt#L24) doesn't throw a checked exception in Kotlin code.

So you can't call the `getStaticWidgets()` in lambda expression since it throws a `IOException` which is a checked exception in Java.

Since you control both the Kotlin and Java code, the simplest solution is to change the parameter type `() -> List<Widget>` to `Callable<List<Widget>>`, for example:

```
// change the parameter type to `Callable` ---v
fun convertExceptionToEmpty(requestFunc: Callable<List<Widget>>): Stream<Widget> {
    try {
        //                 v--- get the `List<Widget>` from `Callable`
        return requestFunc.call().stream()
    } catch (th: Throwable) {
        return Stream.empty()
    }
}
```

**Then** you can use Method Reference Expression in Java8 as further, for example:

```
Stream<Widget> widgets = convertExceptionToEmpty(this::getStaticWidgets);

//OR if `getStaticWidgets` is static `T` is the class belong to
//                                               v
Stream<Widget> widgets = convertExceptionToEmpty(T::getStaticWidgets);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's nothing you can do but catch that exception :

```
 Stream<Integer> widgets = convertExceptionToEmpty(() -> {
        try {
            return getStaticWidgets();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    });
```